# MySQL - grouping data by 2 columns

Tags: mysql, database

I have the follwoing table:
[image: table1]

is it possible if i want to select data to be like this ?
[image: table2]
so, what i need is to group count by caltype and registrationdate(month, year)

any suggestion would be aprreciated thank you :)

Comment: yes it is possible, what query  have you tried?

Comment: This is called 'pivot table', and it's not supported natively by MySQL.

Check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table